# Rebol 3 extension and "handles"

Tags: c, memory-management, handle, rebol, rebol3

In writing a C extension for Rebol3, I need to pass to Rebol a pointer to an object I got from a native function.

1. [The documentation says](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/concepts/extensions-making.html#section-16) that there is a special datatype: *"handle: A way to store code and data pointers"*.  But I would like an example!
2. I want to call a native destructor when this handle is unbound.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: example! That is a new type I have not heard of in Rebol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To store a pointer as a Rebol handle you can do something like this:

```
RXIARG value;
value.addr = original_pointer;
RL_SET_FIELD ( obj, RL_MAP_WORD ( (REBYTE *) "handle-attribute" ), value, RXT_HANDLE );
```

In this example I'm setting the `handle-attribute` attribute of the `obj` object to the value of `original_pointer`

Later you can retrieve the value of the handle like this:

```
int dtype = 0;
RXIARG value;

dtype = RL_GET_FIELD ( obj, RL_MAP_WORD ( (REBYTE *) "handle-attribute" ), &value );

switch ( dtype ) {
  case RXT_NONE:
    printf ( "Invalid handle: none\n" );
    break;

  case RXT_HANDLE:
    original_pointer = value.addr;
    break;

  default:
    printf ( "Invalid handle: none\n" );
}
```

I usually use objects to store handles into, so the `obj` object in the example can be retrieved from Rebol command frame this way:

```
REBSER *obj;
obj = RXA_OBJECT ( frm, 1 );
```

where `frm` is Rebol command frame and `1` is the position of the object in the parameter list passed to your command.

If you want to use blocks to store handles the macros to use to store/retrieve a value from a block are `RL_SET_VALUE` and `RL_GET_VALUE` in place of `RL_*_FIELD`, but the part where you copy your pointer to `value.addr` doesn't change.

You can also return a handle as a result of calling an extension's command by ending the command with the following instructions:

```
RXA_HANDLE ( frm, 1 ) = original_pointer;
RXA_TYPE ( frm, 1 ) = RXT_HANDLE;
return RXR_VALUE;
```

As far as your second question is concerned I think that by now there's no way to know when the handle is unbound or gets garbage collected to trigger a native destructor.